# How to zoom in/out a selected part of an image in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a Qt class project. We're supposed to develop an application like Microsoft Paint. Now I don't know how to enlarge a selected part of an image. Actually I don't even know how to "select" an area. You know, just like that on the desktop of Windows, you press the left button of the mouse and than move it, a dashed-line rectangle will show up. I hope to move or zoom in/out this particular area.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by using mouse events. Here's example that might be useful to you:https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html